# how to do connection pooling on struts framework?

Tags: jakarta-ee, struts, database-connection, connection-pooling

I want to know what library do I need to do connection pooling with struts?
Please give a demo how to do connection pooling with struts framework?
I have read the tutorial by Sun Microsystems but i am not able to understand that tutorial please give a simple demo.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Struts is a presentation framework. Its goal is not to access a database. You use a connection pool with Struts as with any other JEE application. And how to do it depends on your JEE container, not on Struts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to know what library do i need to do connection pooling on
>   struts ?

These are a few connection pooling options which you can choose from

- [BoneCP](http://jolbox.com/)
- [Apache DBCP](http://commons.apache.org/dbcp/)
- [c3p0](http://sourceforge.net/projects/c3p0/)
- [DBPool](http://www.snaq.net/java/DBPool/)

> Please give a demo how to do connection pooling on struts framework ?

It's too much codes if I have to paste here and beside, you should really try it yourself. I found [this](http://jaiswaltraining.com/struts/ch5.php) and [this](http://www.academictutorials.com/struts/struts-databaseconnect.asp) link which can help you along the way of learning and the examples are comprehensive.

The general idea of connection pooling in struts is that you configure the datasource configuration in your struts configuration files (and with the chosen library placed in the correct directory) and then from your action classes, you get the datasource, create the database connection and do the database CRUD.

> How to configure bonecp on struts?

For some reason, in struts 1.3, data-sources is removed (see the struts 1.3 dtd for more info) and if you try to add data-sources in your struts-config.xml, your ide will complaint. Hence, the way to configure datasource, is still possible but not in struts descriptor, you have to use the tomcat web descriptor. Due to the lengthy of the guide, I didn't put them all here, you should visit this [link](http://noflex.org/sh.php?arch=13d6f9fcf4e41cf46d971f6115cb3479&isaction=&searchstr=&email=&password=&blogUID=a96f6c6f0709d9d656cff2848e49db18&entryUID=&commentUID=&anchor=) if you want to learn.

Comment: How to configure BoneCP on struts ?

Comment: @user925689 see the edited answer for more information. I think the material provided should be enough to get you going? I've actually spend hours to get this ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the reply
One more help. Do i have to edit the server.xml and context.xml file placed in conf folder or i can place both file in WEB-INF dir of our project ?

Comment: Yes, from the documentation, this should be possible , read on [how to configure jndi data resources](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/jndi-resources-howto.html). Note,on the directory to place for each descriptor that you asked.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help.
I have tried your code and got a log posted above.
Do you have any idea to fix it ?

Comment: I think that is another question, you should open another question using that log.

Comment: I started a new question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9341330/not-able-to-initialise-application-data-source-on-creating-a-connection-pool-usi please do some reply.

Comment: Can you tell me how to load that server.xml and context.xml file on our online hosting server ?

Comment: I think you are way off from this initial question. Questions are always welcome but please file another question and describe what have you done, what are you expecting and paste your server.xml and context.xml to the question.

Comment: Hey jasonw one last help that i want is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9449679/how-to-edit-the-context-xml-and-server-xml-file-of-hosting-server
Please do some reply