# Not able to initialise application data source on creating a connection pool using BoneCP

Tags: log4j, struts, database-connection, connection-pooling

I have tried database connection pooling using BoneCP with struts but on Running the program i got the folling LOG Please help.
Thanks in advance.

```
Feb 19, 2012 4:52:22 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup
SEVERE: Servlet /DbcpDemo threw load() exception
javax.servlet.UnavailableException: Initializing application data source org.apache.struts.action.DATA_SOURCE
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.initModuleDataSources(ActionServlet.java:812)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.init(ActionServlet.java:335)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1173)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:993)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4421)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:799)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:779)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:601)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:943)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:778)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:504)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1317)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:324)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1065)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
```

Comment: data-sources is removed from the dtd in struts 1.3, see the suggested answer on how to configure the datasource *within* tomcat.

Comment: ya i have coded my apps in the same way what you told earlier. All the things are working correctly. Ican able to fetch the data using your codes. But i got this log on server startup.

Comment: No, the error (line 3-4) show that the data-source is init in the actionservlet. You need to check which version of struts you are using and remove the data-source from struts descriptor.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use Struts to configure a data source. Struts is a presentation framework. It has nothing to do with databases.

See http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html for how to declare and use a DataSource in an application deployed on Tomcat.